# Pushing to main is rejected, Git only pushes to master

Tags: git, github

I'm very confused about the distinction between `main` and `master` branches. Now with GitHub's new `main` branch I wanted to push everything there but instead I found that the command:

```
$ git push -u origin main
```

returned an error message:

```
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/my_account/url.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Git only allows me to push to `master` but I don't understand what the rationale is for that, since:

- that creates a parallel branch and splits up the project
- `main` is the default then why would I want to push to `master`?
- when manually creating the repository on GitHub, a readme.md was also created on `main`. I don't see the added benefit in having the readme on `main` while the code on `master`.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

**Edit: ** Based on a Wes Hardaker's answer below, I deleted the repo and the .git, and did the whole process again. Note that when I did `git init`, Git surprisingly jumped from main to master, so I had to switch back to main afterwards.

```
$ cd "path/to/local/project/folder"
$ git init
$ git checkout -b main
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "commit msg 06/30/2021"
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/my_account/my_repo_name.git
$ git push origin main
```

The last line returned the following error:

```
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/leweex95/Housing-Prices-Prediction.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: The error looks like there are changes on `main` that you do not have locally and that you should update your local `main` before pushing. Have you checked to make sure your updates are on the "latest" main?

Comment: That's true since I created the repo on the GitHub UI and it created a readme file, by default on `main`. My problem is that Git still wants me to push to `master` but I want to store everything in one place, ideally on `main`.

Comment: Git does not care about `main`, `master`, or anything else you want to name a branch. If you want to overwrite `main` and use it but there are changes and you don't want those, have you tried `--force` to force the push?

Comment: I did try it at first but I surely messed up something along the way because before restarting it all from scratch, it didn't help. Now, after redoing everything, `--force` did the trick, thanks a lot!

Comment: As for GitHub, if you create a repo there, either make sure you tell it not to initialize anything (e.g. like a readme.md), you would want to *clone* from there to "get" that stuff it created instead just doing init and pointing to the non-empty repo and expecting to be able to push cleanly.\

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/

Answer (score 0):

There are two notions of branch names, and if you did some manual renaming (in order to move from master to main naming, for example), you can get in this sort of situation.

The easiest fix is to edit your `.git/config` file and change any usage of "master" that you find to "main.

The alternative is actually to delete the remote repository recreate it with `git remote add` and push to it again.

Comment: The config file was a basic one without an mention of the word master. My repo only has a readme on main and a Python script on master. I decided to delete the entire repo and .git folder and restart the process but still facing the exact same error. I'll update my comment with the exact steps taken in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

The hints that git tells you when it fails to push to your remote repository are quite clear:

> hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally... You may want to **first integrate** the remote changes
> hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

You are left with two basic options:

1. `git pull` or `git pull --rebase` in order to bring the **remote** changes locally.
2. `git push --force` which **will override** (dangerous!!) your remote changes.

`git` itself doesn't care about if your branch is called `master` or `main`. GitHub is not the same as `git` the app, hence just because GitHub is now configured to work with main doesn't change the behavior of git.

---

Side note: you can change the configuration of GitHub to use `master` by default when creating repositories (instead of it being `main`).

Answer (score -1):

```
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

These steps worked for me to resolve this error:

```
$ git fetch origin main:tmp 

$ git rebase tmp

//Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/main.

$ git push --set-upstream origin main

$ git push
```